# Open Source nginx reverse to multiple servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have one server running the open-source version of Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04 with an IP address of 192.168.1.50.  I have three other web servers that I am trying to reverse proxy to.  I have 3 files in my conf.d folder; `server1.example.com.conf`, `server2.example.com.conf` and `server3.example.com.conf` with IPs assigned of `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2` and `192.168.1.3` respectively.  Since the Nginx server is not hosting web sites, I have not put anything in the /var/www/html folder.  My DNS points all 3 web servers to 192.168.1.50.

My config files look like this:

server1.example.com.conf looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server1.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/server1_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/server1_error.log;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server1.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.key;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass "https://192.168.1.1";
```

server2.example.com.conf looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server2.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/server2_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/server2_error.log;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server2.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.key;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass "https://192.168.1.2";
```

server3.example.com.conf looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server3.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/server3_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/server3_error.log;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server3.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mytestdomain.key;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass "https://192.168.1.3";
```

Unfortunately, I have changed the configurations so many times, I cannot remember which versions worked and did not work.  The config that somewhat worked sends me only to server1.example.com no matter which server I go to.

What part of the above config is telling all traffic to redirect to `server1.example.com only`, and am I trying to do something that won't work?

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: All three configurations are incomplete. The client you are using, uses SNI? Is your certifcate a wildcard or does it over all three domains?

Comment: Thanks for offing up some advice.  That was just one of many configurations I created through time.  I did get it working this morning.  I reloaded Ubuntu, again for the probably 10th time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for offing up some advice. That was just one of many configurations I created through time.  My certificate is a wildcard issued by GoDaddy. Something I found on another post was to make sure the nginx web site was working. "curl -i [http://127.0.0.1/nginx_status"](http://127.0.0.1/nginx_status%22) and check the services "systemctl status nginx". Curl error'd out but the services looked ok. The good news for me is that I did get it working this morning. I reloaded Ubuntu from scratch, again, for the probably 15th time. This time though, I followed nginx's install documentation rather than just doing a sudo apt-install nginx.  Also, instead of making individual config files, I put them all in one file called mytestdomain.com.conf.  The 3 servers I am redirecting to are normal http port 80 servers I built to make sure everything is working.  I added a live server to the config, which is the reason I started this project.  When trying to go to that server, I got the message "The page isn’t redirecting properly". I tried other live servers and got the same error.  What I learned is that web servers that have a SSL re-write or any other mechanism in place to force redirection from http over to https do not work on nginx. At least not mine.  For now it's not worth re configuring my servers that work and taking the chance that I break something else. When this certificate expires, I will port the servers over to nginx rather than recert all of then.

Thanks again for stepping up and trying to help me out!! My simple project had gotten very frustrating.